# How to prevent RCP exit failure?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I was writing a program yesterday, I failed to exit Eclipse. The UI is closed, but the console is still running (eclipsec.exe). This kind of problem is not common. I checked the error log and found no reason.

How can I avoid this kind of problem if I develop an RCP? Can I check the thread when the Display is destroyed, and force exit (System.exit) after the specified time

Is my method feasible?

Comment: `eclipsec.exe` is not the console, but the command line equivalent of `eclipse.exe` to be used for a headless Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: When eclipsec.exe starts, the window with a black background, isn't it the console? What is his name then?
i don't know what to call him

Comment: `eclipsec.exe` is the executable for the command line alias console. When not called from the command line, e.g. when you double-click it in the Windows file explorer, it opens a console (`cmd`). Using it for a non headless application (as in your case) does not make sense.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Let me explain, I run through eclipsec because I want to see some exception information output through System.out

Comment: In my question, I used (eclipsec. exe) because I didn't know how to express the black, console like window. I think I wrote (eclipsec. exe), and you will understand

Comment: Use the `-debug` parameter for that with or without an `.options` file. For [details see here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePerformance/article.html#using-the-build-in-tracing-facilities-of-eclipse). Regarding your problem about exiting your RCP application, have you checked in the _Task Manager_ whether there is still a Java process running?

Comment: I have no problem with my RCP program, but I'm worried about this kind of problem. If a commercial software has this kind of problem, I think it is a disaster

Comment: So, I want to ask you, is my solution feasible? Is there anything better.

Comment: Better fix the root cause that prevents your RCP application from exiting rather than using a hack like `System.exit`. Does your RCP creates threads that are still running instead of using the jobs API? Or maybe some jobs are deadlocked and cannot be canceled (be also aware of [this](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.26/platform_isv.php#JobManager_Implementation))? Whatever, maybe you can find the root cause by debugging your RCP application.